# Is there a list of Concentration Spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, concentration

The concentration mechanic is a very significant restriction in D&D 5e. I was wondering if there was a list somewhere of all these spells?

Bonus if they're segregated by level, class, and/or school (similar to [this](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/DnD_SpellLists_1.0.pdf) list, but it doesn't show whether or not spells require concentration).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have personally found [this](http://donjon.bin.sh/5e/spells/) tool very useful. It's an online spell list, sortable by class, level, school, casting time, what components it has, whether it's a ritual or not, and whether it requires concentration.

Comment: I like this answer better than mine.  Is it reasonable to edit this answer with information from my answer, then delete my answer?

Comment: I'm not sure what purpose that would serve, to be honest. Leave your answer up, some people might prefer an excel sheet to an online tool. If you feel my answer mentions something that your answer does not, you could always edit your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

There is a sortable spell list here:

http://mouseferatu.com/index.php/news/august-8-2014-a-special-gift-for-my-fellow-dd-fans/

that includes a column for concentration.